# How to convert a categorical variable with multiple values into several binary variable in sql?

Tags: sql, pivot

Given a character variable with multiple values (in my example `product`), how can I convert it into several dichotomous variables simultaneously grouping by another variable (in my example `customer`) ?

Example: How can I convert the data from

```
customer     product
custumerA    productA
customerA    productA
customerA    productC
customerA    productD
customerB    productB
customerB    productD
...
```

into

```
customer      productA    productB   productC  productD  .... productZ
customerA     1           0          1         1              0
customerB     0           1          0         1              0
```

...

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql+pivot)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the products you want, use aggregation:

```
select customer,
       max(case when product = 'productA' then 1 else 0 end) as productA,
       max(case when product = 'productB' then 1 else 0 end) as productB,
       max(case when product = 'productC' then 1 else 0 end) as productC,
       max(case when product = 'productD' then 1 else 0 end) as productD
from t
group by customer;
```

If you don't know the list of products, you will need dynamic SQL, and how to do that depends on the database.

Answer (score 0):

**Dynamic Pivot Query**

```
Declare @sql nvarchar(max)

set @sql='select * from (select customer, product, count(product)Cnt from #mytable group by customer, product)tbl
          Pivot
         (sum(Cnt) for product In ('+stuff( (select distinct ', '+ product from #mytable for xml path('')),1,1,'')  +') ) as PivotTable'

 execute sp_executesql @sql
```

[image]